# Errno 14 PYCURL ERROR 6 ; Couldn't resolve host in Cloudera Manager 7.x upgrade

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am doing an upgrade from Cloudera CM 5.16 to CM 7.1.2. There is an instruction to enter userid:password in the url in the /etc/yum.repos.d/cloudera-manager.repo file when using the Cloudera public repository:

Substitute your USERNAME and PASSWORD in the Package Repository URL where indicated in the URL:
`baseurl=https://USERID:PASSWORD@archive.cloudera.com/p/cm7/7.1.2/redhat6/yum/`.
After setting this and running the command: `yum deplist cloudera-manager-agent` 
it gives an error below:

........@archive.cloudera.com/p/cm7/7.1.2/redhat6/yum/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'xyz.com:password@archive.cloudera.com'"

Anyone seen this error and how to resolve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the USERID:PASSWORD in the url will be provided by Cloudera after license is purchased.